# mysql query not inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a simple form to have users request supplies but on submit it keeps giving me a generic error. I don't see where my mistake is...

```
     CREATE TABLE `teacherrequests` (
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `binder` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `binderpage` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `binderdiv` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `calcr` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `chalkcolor` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `chalkwhite` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `chalkeraser` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `colpencil` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `dryerasecleaner` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `dryeraser` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `dryerasemarkers` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `filefolders` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `gluesticks` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `hangingfile` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `highlightermulti` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `highlighterone` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `holepunch3` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `holepunch1` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `index35` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `index57` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `markers` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `papergraph` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `paperlegal` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `papersteno` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `paperwhitelined` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `paperclipsbindlg` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `paperclipsbindmd` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `paperclipsbindsm` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `paperclipslg` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `paperclipsmd` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `paperclipssm` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `pencil` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `pencilsharp` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `pensblack` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `pensblue` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `pensgreen` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `pensred` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `permanentmarker` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `postit` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `postitsmall` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `stapler` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `staples` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `tapedbl` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `tapemasking` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `tapescotch` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `tapedispenser` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `tacks` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `clock` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `whiteout` varchar(2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here's the code...

I've checked these against my form and they all match up.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$binder = $_POST['binder'];
$binderpage = $_POST['binderpage'];
$binderdiv = $_POST['binderdiv'];
$calc = $_POST['calc'];
$chalkcolor = $_POST['chalkcolor'];
$chalkwhite = $_POST['chalkwhite'];
$chalkeraser = $_POST['chalkeraser'];
$colpencil = $_POST['colpencil'];
$dryerasecleaner = $_POST['dryerasecleaner'];
$dryeraser = $_POST['dryeraser'];
$dryerasemarkers = $_POST['dryerasemarkers'];
$filefolders = $_POST['filefolders'];
$gluesticks = $_POST['gluesticks'];
$hangingfile = $_POST['hangingfile'];
$highlightermulti = $_POST['highlightermulti'];
$highlighterone = $_POST['highlighterone'];
$holepunch3 = $_POST['holepunch3'];
$holepunch1 = $_POST['holepunch1'];
$index35 = $_POST['index35'];
$index57 = $_POST['index57'];
$markers = $_POST['markers'];
$papergraph = $_POST['papergraph'];
$paperlegal = $_POST['paperlegal'];
$papersteno = $_POST['papersteno'];
$paperwhitelined = $_POST['paperwhitelined'];
$paperclipsbindlg = $_POST['paperclipsbindlg'];
$paperclipsbindmd = $_POST['paperclipsbindmd'];
$paperclipsbindsm = $_POST['paperclipsbindsm'];
$pencil = $_POST['pencil'];
$pencilsharp = $_POST['pencilsharp'];
$pensblack = $_POST['pensblack'];
$pensblue = $_POST['pensblue'];
$pensgreen = $_POST['pensgreen'];
$pensred = $_POST['pensred'];
$permanentmarker = $_POST['permanentmarker'];
$postit = $_POST['postit'];
$postitsmall = $_POST['postitsmall'];
$stapleremover = $_POST['stapleremover'];
$stapler = $_POST['stapler'];
$staples = $_POST['staples'];
$tapedbl = $_POST['tapedbl'];
$tapemasking = $_POST['tapemasking'];
$tapescotch = $_POST['tapescotch'];
$tapedispenser = $_POST['tapedispenser'];
$tacks = $_POST['tacks'];
$clock = $_POST['clock'];
$whiteout = $_POST['whiteout'];
```

I assume my error is here but I can't seem to find it.

```
// Insert data into mysql 

$sql="INSERT INTO teacherrequests(name, binder, binderpage, binderdiv, calcr, 
chalkcolor, chalkwhite, chalkeraser, colpencil, dryerasecleaner, dryeraser,     
dryerasemarkers, filefolders, gluesticks, hangingfile, highlightermulti, highlighterone,     
holepunch3, holepunch1, index35, index57, markers, papergraph, paperlegal, papersteno,     
paperwhitelined, paperclipsbindlg, paperclipsbindmd, paperclipsbindsm, pencil,     
pencilsharp, pensblack, pensblue, pensgreen, pensred, permanentmarker, postit,     
postitsmall, stapleremover, stapler, staples, tapedbl, tapemasking, tapescotch,     
tapedispenser, tacks, clock, whiteout)

VALUES('$name', '$binder', '$binderpage',     
'$binderdiv', '$calc', '$chalkcolor', '$chalkwhite', '$chalkeraser', '$colpencil',     
'$dryerasecleaner', '$dryeraser', '$dryerasemarkers', '$filefolders', '$gluesticks',     
'$hangingfile', '$highlightermulti', '$highlighterone', '$holepunch3', '$holepunch1',     
'$index35', '$index57', '$markers', '$papergraph', '$paperlegal', '$papersteno',     
'$paperwhitelined', '$paperclipsbindlg', '$paperclipsbindmd', '$paperclipsbindsm',     
'$pencil', '$pencilsharp', '$pensblack', '$pensblue', '$pensgreen', '$pensred',     
'$permanentmarker', '$postit', '$postitsmall', '$stapleremover', '$stapler', '$staples',     
'$tapedbl', '$tapemasking', '$tapescotch', '$tapedispenser', '$tacks', '$clock',    
'$whiteout')";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Here is the var_dump:

```
ERRORstring(811) "INSERT INTO teacherrequests(name, binder, binderpage, binderdiv, calcr, chalkcolor, chalkwhite, chalkeraser, colpencil, dryerasecleaner, dryeraser, dryerasemarkers, filefolders, gluesticks, hangingfile, highlightermulti, highlighterone, holepunch3, holepunch1, index35, index57, markers, papergraph, paperlegal, papersteno, paperwhitelined, paperclipsbindlg, paperclipsbindmd, paperclipsbindsm, pencil, pencilsharp, pensblack, pensblue, pensgreen, pensred, permanentmarker, postit, postitsmall, stapleremover, stapler, staples, tapedbl, tapemasking, tapescotch, tapedispenser, tacks, clock, whiteout)VALUES('Joe Spano', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '4', '', '', '', '', '', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')"
```

Comment: What's the generic error that you're getting?

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump` on $result? If it's null, it's likely that `mysql_query` encountered an error.

Comment: Oh no, [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!

Comment: It looks like you have about fifty SQL injection vulnerabilities in your code.

Comment: And about a thousand VARCHAR(2) fields. I'm... not quite sure about this database design.

Comment: You could check out [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to at least see (and tell us) the error you are triggering.

Comment: @Joe add this to your mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($dbc)); where $dbc is your database connection. That should tell you whats wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at

```
 `calcr` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
```

on your create table code as compared to

```
$calc = $_POST['calc'];
```

in  your php code. I'm guessing it's just a simple typo with the extra "r" on the end.

I also found these lines of code did not have an accompanying line in the other file:

```
  `paperclipslg` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `paperclipsmd` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `paperclipssm` varchar(2) NOT NULL,

  $stapleremover = $_POST['stapleremover'];
```

Hope that helps!

**[EDIT]** I didn't see any discrepancies between your inserts and your values though. So now that I look at this more, I don't think I've helped fix the problem. I only found some data that you may be missing.

Comment: He has `INSERT INTO teacherrequests(..., calcr, ...) VALUES (..., $calc, ...)` so I don't think that's it.

Comment: The second part fixed the problem.  $stapleremover was missing from the database and those other variables weren't being passed along.

Thank you

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that the calc vs calcr wouldn't create any problems. It was just an "error" in my head because I like to name all my data the same.

Answer (score 14):

The first thing you should do is to take this database design and throw it in the trash. Then replace it with this design:

```
CREATE TABLE teachingmaterials (
    id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB CHARACTER SET utf8;

INSERT INTO
    teachingmaterials
    (name)
VALUES
    ('binder'),
    ('binder-page'),
    ('binder-div'),
    -- put the rest of them in here --
    ('whiteout');

CREATE TABLE teacherrequests (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB CHARACTER SET utf8;

CREATE TABLE teacherrequests_teachingmaterials (
    teacherrequests_id INT NOT NULL,
    teachingmaterials_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    amount SMALLINT,
    note VARCHAR(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (teacherrequests_id, teachingmaterials_id)
    FOREIGN KEY (teacherrequests_id) REFERENCES teacherrequests (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (teachingmaterials_id) REFERENCES teachingmaterials (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

You also need to stop using the old `mysql_*` functions and switch to using PDO instead.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this out. I'm obviously new at this and have little experience with db design.